# Optional positional argument in flag package

Tags: go, flags

Is there a way to accept optional positional argument, and set a default value if such argument wasn't parsed?

```
I tried with a new flagset, but then a positional argument is required.
And when I try this version:
```

```
var (
filter                 = flag.String("filter", "", "")
having                 = flag.String("having", "", "")
fields                 = flag.String("fields", "", "")
format                 = flag.String("format", "", "")
limit                  = flag.Int("limit", 0, "")

main{
flag.Usage = help
flag.Parse()
if flag.NArg() > 0 {
    table = flag.Args()[0]
}
```

```
It ignores the other flags that are not positional.
What am I doing wrong?
```

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to accept optional positional argument, and set a default value if such argument wasn't parsed?

No.